# SQL Distinct records on multiple conditional query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get `Distinct` results using `EntityFramework` and `MS SQL` query and filtering records on two conditions so I have used `Distinct()`

here is my code:

```
public List<ProductViewModel> GetPagedFilterProducts(int page, int type_id1, int type_id2)
{
    int recordsPerPage = 20;
    var skipRecords = page * recordsPerPage;
    var results = _products.GetAll().Where(p => p.type1 == type_id1 && p.type2 == type_id2).Select(p => new ProductViewModel
    {
        productId = p.product_id,
        productTitle = p.product_title,
    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.productTitle).Skip(skipRecords).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList();
    return results.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

I am using checkboxes to filter the records, so `type_id` can be more than two conditions (I mean there could be `type_id3`). How should I query so user can select more than two type conditions and it still gives me `Distinct` results.

**How can I query on each condition separately and combine them together and get the `Distinct` results?**

Please forgive me if I didn't explain my question properly.

Comment: @GrantWinney: So sorry, that query was just for example, I have edited it. Please check now. Thanks

Comment: Query on each condition separately: `p => p.type1 == type_id1 || p.type2 == type_id2`

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<ProductViewModel> GetPagedFilterProducts(int page, int type_id1, int type_id2)
{
  int recordsPerPage = 20;
  var skipRecords = page * recordsPerPage;
  var results = _products.GetAll().Where(p => p.type == type_id1 || p.type == type_id2).Select(p => new ProductViewModel
  {
    productId = p.product_id,
    productTitle = p.product_title,
  }).OrderByDescending(p => p.productTitle)
  .Skip(skipRecords)
  .Take(recordsPerPage).ToList();

  return results.Distinct().ToList();
```

}

The basic idea behind the query,Value of checkbox for selecting items will compare in a table with a single column .